# Import directory of docx files

Tags: r

I have a directory with .docx files that I want to import via textreadr's [read_docx function](https://github.com/trinker/textreadr#read-docx).

First I set the working directory and create list of files:

```
setwd("C:/R")
files <- list.files("C:/R", pattern = "\\.docx")
```

Now I want to iterate through the list and import every file individually, named data_"file":

```
for (file in files) {
  assign("data_", file, sep = "") <- read_docx("file")
  }
```

Optionally, I tried creating a list of lists:

```
data_list <- lapply(files, function(v){
  read_docx("v")
})
```

Both variants don't work and I'm not sure what I do wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the full path is not present,  we can add

```
files <- list.files("C:/R", pattern = "\\.docx", full.names = TRUE)
```

The issue is that `v` or `file` is quoted i.e. `""` i.e. it is trying to read a string "v" instead of the value.  Thus, the code in the OP's post can be corrected to

```
data_list <- lapply(files, function(v){
  read_docx(v)
})
```

or in the `for` loop

```
for (file in files) {
  assign(paste0("data_", file, sep = ""), read_docx(file))
  }
```

Also, as noted in the comments, if there are 1000 files, `assign` creates 1000 new objects which is a bit messy when we want to gather all of them again.  Instead, as in the `lapply`, which creates a single `list`, the output from `for` loop can be store in a `list`

```
data_list2 <- vector('list', length(files))
names(data_list2) <- files
for(file in files) {
   data_list2[[file]] <- read_docx(file)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I should have mentioned that the working directory is set.

Comment: @ab0rt in the description, there is no issue mentioned.  Can you suggest what is the question about

Comment: of course, thanks. The issue is that both variants don't work and I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: @ab0rt it works if you do the update in my post

Answer (score 2):

First off, you need to grab the *full path* instead of just the filenames from `list.files`:

```r
files <- list.files("C:/R", pattern = "\\.docx$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Then the `lapply` solution works if you pass the parameter `v` to `read_docx` instead of a literal string `"v"`. You don’t even need the nested function:

```r
data_list <- lapply(files, read_docx)
```

As an aside, there’s no need for `setwd` in your code, and [its use is strongly discouraged](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/).

Furthermore, using the `assign` function as in your code doesn’t work and even after fixing the syntax, this use is simply completely inappropriate: at best it is a hack that approximates the functionality of lists, but badly. The correct solution, 10 times out of 10, is to use a named list or vector in its place.